# WPF/C# Combobox Only Changes Selection When A Click is Detected Outside of Text Area

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

So I have several comboboxes in my WPF application that don't change the selection when a user clicks on the text of a combobox item.  In order to select a particular item you have to click to the right or left of the text.  I have another combobox that selects just fine when the text is clicked.  The only difference between the two is databinding.  The comboboxes that don't select when the text is clicked are databound to an ObservableCollection of one type or another. The combobox that works has manually inserted, static values.

I've searched the issue extensively and I can't seem to find anyone else who has had this issue or anything remotely similar.  I'm not setting any weird properties.

Here is the code for one of the problematic comboboxes:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Systems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=System}" SelectedIndex="0">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```

Here is a video of the behavior:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0r1N1ghw-k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enter code here`Suppose my Combobox is defind as below

```
 <ComboBox Name="cmb" Width="200" Height="20" DisplayMemberPath="PersonName" SelectedValuePath="PersonID">

    </ComboBox>
```

**please notice , i have removed the itemtemplate part**

and my model is as below

```
public class Person
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    public string PersonID { get; set; }
}
```

And my binding is in code behind , this step is not necessary , you can do it in the xaml , iam just checking quickly so much dirty code

```
 public List<Person> source = new List<Person>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            source.Add(new Person() { PersonID = i.ToString(), PersonName = "Sau" + i.ToString() });
        }
        cmb.ItemsSource = source;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

so if you run this sample , you will see you can select the value when you click on the text itself.

it's content property which causes some problem but i am not 100% sure on this.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem. It's still behaving the same way. Is there anything I can do to debug this a little better?  I don't know if I've described the problem accurately, or if I've left something important out.

Comment: Still the same thing.  As far as the binding is concerned, it's loading all of the right data, and I'm able to change the selection as well, I just can't change selection unless I click to the right or left of the text for that particular combobox item.  I've tried using IsReadOnly and had the same result. This is happening on multiple machines as well.

Comment: :), i am also digging this up , how is this strange behaviour?

Comment: Well one would expect to be able to click anywhere on a combobox item to select it.  Like I mentioned in my post above, I have another combobox that works as expected, but its content isn't loaded through data binding.  We've done some usability testing on the application and everyone is noticing this.  It's just an annoyance that I would like to work out.  If need be I can try to make a video of the behavior...that might better explain exactly what is happening.

Comment: i have found the cause may be this can help you , updating my answer.

Comment: Please let me know if its solves your propem and don't fporgot to accept the answer as it will increse your accept % on this site so that you will get timely response to your questions in future

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thank you so much.  That's quite a strange thing to have happen, but I'm glad it's working now.

Comment: Are there any better solutions, involving an ItemTemplate? I'm facing the same issue.